# Si envio un archivo a azure por una app web, como recibo respuesta de la llegada del archivo desde azure hasta la app web?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, signalr

estoy desarrollando una app web con js, que se conecta a Azure con signalR, me gustaria saber como puedo recibir una respuesta desde azure una vez que llega el archivo, que me confirme en la app web la llegada del archivo y con esto poder activar una funcion.

resumo, una vez recibido el archivo en azure, como me daria azure una confirmacion que pueda usarla en la web para provocar una funcion.

gracias de ante mano por la ayuda.